# What is the correct way to collect the string input from cin from <iostream> and convert it to a double?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



//Initializing some variables.

string PairOfAverage = "blank";
string ConsoleInput = "";
double OrderEntry = 0;
double OrderAmount = 0;
double WeightFactor1[] = {};
double WeightFactor2 = 0;
string inputString = "";


int main() {

    cout<< "Do you wish to determine average position for a pair? " << endl;
    cout << "Please answer \"true\" or \"false\"."<< endl;
    cin >> ConsoleInput;
```

//Here you should input "true" or "false".

```
    bool DetermineAverage = ToBool(ConsoleInput); 

    cout << "Please enter the currency pair Symbol in XXXYYY format:";
    cin >> PairOfAverage;
```

//Here you should input a string.

```
    for (int i=0;DetermineAverage==true;i++) {

        cout << "Please enter the order's entry price: ";
        cin >> inputString;
```

//Here input should be a double.

```
        OrderEntry = stod (inputString,NULL);
        cout << "Please enter the order's amount: ";
        cin >> inputString;
```

//Here input should be a double.

```
        OrderAmount = stod (inputString,NULL);
        sleep(1);
        cout << OrderAmount << " <-- OrderAmount" << endl;
        WeightFactor1[i] = OrderEntry*OrderAmount;
        WeightFactor2 += OrderAmount;
        cout << "weight factor: " << WeightFactor2 << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to introduce more orders for the same pair? " << endl;
        cout << "Please answer \"true\" or \"false\"."<< endl;
        cin >> ConsoleInput;
```

//Here you should input "true" or "false".

```
        DetermineAverage = ToBool(ConsoleInput);

        sleep(1);
        if (DetermineAverage == false) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i ; j++){
                sum+=WeightFactor1[j];
                cout<<"sum equals: " << sum << " " << j << endl;
            }
            double result = sum/WeightFactor2;
            cout<< "Average Price for " << WeightFactor2 << " units of " << PairOfAverage << " is: " << result << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//This is a function to parse the string to bool type.

```
bool ToBool(string ConsoleInput){
    bool InputBool ;
    if (ConsoleInput == "false"){
        InputBool = false;
    }
    else if(ConsoleInput == "true"){
        InputBool = true;
    }
    return(InputBool);
}

 //The error I get is the result of variable WeightFactor2. It does not add up
 //the sum of the introduced valued the where passed as string through cin>>
 //and then parsed to double.
 //I hope you can help me on this.
```

Comment: Why not cin >> OrderEntry; or cin >> OrderAmount; directly?

Comment: Thank!. I did this first, and it worked. But the calculation error comes after. When I introduce 100 for OrderAmount I get WeightFactor2 = 100. Then I introduce 200 for OrderAmount and what should produce WeightFactor2 = 300. (WeightFactor2 += OrderSize) produces WeightFactor2 = 1100. This is the problem I tried to solve by parsing the string to double. But using any of the two methods I get the same result

Comment: That is not because of the cin >> OrderAmount;  Rather you are working on an WeightFactor2 which is a pointer to undefined space that you did not allocate at all.  Use std::vector or define a finite length for the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for using conversion? You can read the input any primitive type you want, so you can directly read `bool` or `double` values such as `cin >> OrderAmount`. No need for string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The input stream has an [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for `double`.

```
double value;
std::cin >> value;
```

There you go. This is the canonical way to convert standard input into a `double`.

Comment: I did this first, and it worked. But the calculation error comes after. When I introduce 100 for OrderAmount I get WeightFactor2 = 100. Then I introduce 200 for OrderAmount and what should produce WeightFactor2 = 300. (WeightFactor2 += OrderSize) produces WeightFactor2 = 1100. This is the problem I tried to solve by parsing the string to double. But using any of the two methods I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your usage of double WeightFactor1[] = {} to vector< double > WeightFactor1;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



//Initializing some variables.

string PairOfAverage = "blank";
string ConsoleInput = "";
double OrderEntry = 0;
double OrderAmount = 0;
vector< double > WeightFactor1;
double WeightFactor2 = 0;
string inputString = "";

bool ToBool(string ConsoleInput){
    bool InputBool ;
    if (ConsoleInput == "false"){
        InputBool = false;
    }
    else if(ConsoleInput == "true"){
        InputBool = true;
    }
    return(InputBool);
}


int main() {

    cout<< "Do you wish to determine average position for a pair? " << endl;
    cout << "Please answer \"true\" or \"false\"."<< endl;
    cin >> ConsoleInput; 
//Here you should input "true" or "false".

    bool DetermineAverage = ToBool(ConsoleInput); 

    cout << "Please enter the currency pair Symbol in XXXYYY format:";
    cin >> PairOfAverage; 
//Here you should input a string.

    for (int i=0;DetermineAverage==true;i++) {

        cout << "Please enter the order's entry price: ";
        cin >> OrderEntry;
//Here input should be a double.

        cout << "Please enter the order's amount: ";
        cin >> OrderAmount;
//Here input should be a double.

        //sleep(1);
        cout << OrderAmount << " <-- OrderAmount" << endl;
        WeightFactor1.push_back( OrderEntry*OrderAmount );
        WeightFactor2 += OrderAmount;
        cout << "weight factor: " << WeightFactor2 << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to introduce more orders for the same pair? " << endl;
        cout << "Please answer \"true\" or \"false\"."<< endl;
        cin >> ConsoleInput; 
//Here you should input "true" or "false".

        DetermineAverage = ToBool(ConsoleInput);

        //sleep(1);
        if (DetermineAverage == false) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i ; j++){
                sum+=WeightFactor1[j];
                cout<<"sum equals: " << sum << " " << j << endl;
            }
            double result = sum/WeightFactor2;
            cout<< "Average Price for " << WeightFactor2 << " units of " << PairOfAverage << " is: " << result << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//This is a function to parse the string to bool type.


 //The error I get is the result of variable WeightFactor2. It does not add up
 //the sum of the introduced valued the where passed as string through cin>>
 //and then parsed to double.
 //I hope you can help me on this.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction of giving an initial size to the array. Before using vector I used double WeightFactor1[100] = {}; with and I got the correct result. now I'm using vector but I also had to input a size to get the code to work.